# short term load forecasting with arima model in python

Tags: python, forecasting

I have a time series datasets(y=kwh and x=some features like time, month, day, year e.t.) and I want to make a prediction. I want to use ARIMA models but I don't know how.I am new in ARIMA and I want someone to guide me step by step.Thank you.

Comment: statsmodels has a notebook on ARMA http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/examples/notebooks/generated/tsa_arma_0.html

Comment: @Scott Thank you.May you explain me the first step that must follow?